Is there a wavelength shift between sunlight observed from the ISS versus from Earth's surface?
As gasses are not ideal in transmitting sunlight. Are there differences between sunlight observed from beyond the Earth atmosphere and the one observed from the Earth surface? If so, what are they?

The atmosphere does not shift the frequency of light, but it does scatter and attenuate the radiation.   The graph below shows the relative intensity of solar radiation at the top of the atmosphere and at the bottom.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg
Human vision already color corrects in many situations.   While the sunlight visible from the ISS would be brighter and have a slightly different spectrum, I doubt a person would be able to tell a difference of the color profile between the inside and outside of the atmosphere.

There is still of course the ~20 ppm (max) Doppler shift of all the spectral features large and small for the light seen from Low Earth orbit (it's a lot smaller for the rotating Earth's surface) and of course all those narrow telluric absorption lines seen from Earth's surface.

And I will add the gravitational blueshift as the light comes down our gravity well.  I don't know if it even could be measured with current tech, it certainly isn't noticeable.

@LorenPechtel The gravitational time dilation at the ISS altitude (~417.6 km) relative to sea level is ~1+4.3e-11, which is easy to measure as a frequency shift of a specific signal (eg a maser) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment But I agree it would be very hard to detect as a shift of a broad spectrum signal like sunlight.

@LorenPechtel that would make an excellent new question if you're interested! Not sure, but perhaps Astronomy SE is the better place to ask it? I'm guessing the answer is that it would be really, really hard - even top layers of the Sun's atmosphere are pretty hot, so thermal doppler broadening would be really really huge in comparison. It might be a tad easier to see the gravitational red shift of those lines due to the Sun's gravity compared to far less red-shifted laboratory lines on Earth. It's still really hard, but it's possible someone at least tried.

@uhoh I already deleted it as I saw it's addressed by his link.  Too much doppler and redshifting variation of the source, it's swamped.

@LorenPechtel yep yep. While we can measure the centroid of a symmetric distribution to a teeny tiny fraction of it's width, any asymmetry in the shape (especially if there's uncertainty in that shape) nixes it, and Doppler from some net radial motion and uncertainties in other atomic shifts seem to add an additional layer of hopelessness for an unambiguous, unimpeachable measurement.

The graph shows clearly that the average wavelength of sunlight is longer after it has passed through the atmosphere (about 50% of the blue light is absorbed or scattered, but only 10 or 20% of the red light), so should the first word not be "yes"?? Of course, "shifting" is a funny term, but if wavelength 2 is longer than wavelength 1 we can surely call that a "shift".

There is a miniscule relativistic blue shift as photons fall into earth's gravity well. At any given altitude half of that shift is undone by the transverse velocity of an orbiting body. So the ISS has slightly less than 50% of the blue-shift that's experienced upon the earth's surface.
However this is dwarfed by the alternating blue-shift moving towards the sun at dawn and red-shift receding from the sun at sunset, every 45 minutes aboard the ISS and every 12 hours on the earth's surface.
Before that happens, light leaving the sun is subject to gravitational red shift (making the sun seem ever so slightly cooler than it really is), but that doesn't affect the relative shift between the ISS and the earth's surface.
None of these effects is visible to the human eye.
